# PFQueryTableViewController loadObjects() flashes screen

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Right now I'm doing this:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);
    self.loadObjects()
}
```

But every time I use loadObjects(), the screen briefly flashes. I don't know how to fix it. I am using a TabBarController (no segues between views), so each view is only loaded once, and I want to update each view when I navigate to it. loadObjects() works, it just creates this annoying visual bug. I assume that the old view is cached and is desplayed before the new one is loaded, and that's why I see this flash. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question by any chance? I experience the same issue.